# Postgres Docker- How to enable postgres docker to allow remote connections?

Tags: docker, postgresql, remote-access

I hope to connect my Postgres docker service from remote client. This is how I create the container:

```
sudo docker run --name pg -p 5432:5432 -v pg_data:/var/lib/postgres/data -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb -e POSTGRES_USER=dbowner -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=MySecretPassword -d postgres -c "listen_addresses='*'"
```

I do research and someone said the file `pg_hba.conf` should be edited. How should I edit pg_hba.conf? There has no config parameters to setup the `pg_hba.conf`. Also, is there any deferences between `host all all all md5` and `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`? Which one should I use and how should put it into `pg_hba.conf` within the docker container?

Here is the output of `netstat` after I create container:

```
$ netstat -ntl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::4000                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::4001                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Is that means PostgreSQL service only listen to IPv6?

Comment: Please check other  answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694987/connecting-to-postgresql-in-a-docker-container-from-outside

Comment: @sanjayparmar I have tried this before, and as my description shows the command that I used to create the container is similar to the one in the answer and it does not work.

Comment: Do not crosspost: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117600/postgres-docker-how-to-enable-postgres-docker-to-allow-remote-connections

Comment: @Rob okay, I have deleted that one.

Answer (score 2):

There are errors in `-v option`:

- You write `/var/lib/postgres/data` it should be `/var/lib/postgresql/data`
- The host path must be full: `/root/pgdata`
- If the host using selinux then use `-v /root/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z` or if not use `:rw` instead

This is running perfectly:

```
root@testubt:~# docker run --name pg -p 5432:5432 -v /root/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb -e POSTGRES_USER=dbowner -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=MySecretPassword -d postgres:alpine


root@testubt:~# ss -tnl | grep 5432
LISTEN     0      128         :::5432                    :::*
```

Test localhost:

```
root@testubt:~# PGPASSWORD=MySecretPassword psql -U dbowner mydb -h localhost
psql (9.5.14, server 10.5)
Type "help" for help.

mydb=# \q
```

Test from other machine:

```
alp01:~# PGPASSWORD=MySecretPassword psql -U dbowner mydb -h testubt
psql (10.5)
Type "help" for help.

mydb=#
```

And if you want to edit `pg_hba.conf` it is in the `/root/pgdata` directory. which I believed you won't needed.

Cheers :)

Comment: My `pg_data` is a docker volume, should still use `/root/pg_data` instead? And what's the meaning of `:Z` and `:rw`?

Comment: you don't need /root/pgdata  if using docker volume.

Comment: for selinux things see the docker selinux manual at https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label